# Minimum value of $ \displaystyle \frac{\int_{0}^{1}{[f'(x)]^2 \ dx}}{\int_{0}^{1}{[f(x)]^2 \ dx}} $

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

Let there be a function $f(x)$ double differentiable in $[0,1]$ and it is given that $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ while $f(x)$ is not identically zero. So find the smallest possible value of

$$ \displaystyle \frac{\int_{0}^{1}{[f'(x)]^2 \ dx}}{\int_{0}^{1}{[f(x)]^2 \ dx}} $$

I have tried using IBP which seems inevitable to the first sight but of not much significance, u-substitution too does not make it quite clear.

How to do such kinds of problems anyway? It doesn't seems to me that it requires any advanced stuff.

Comment: This is the Rayleigh–Ritz quotient for the Dirichlet eigenvalue problem $-u''=\lambda u$, $u(0)=u(1)=0$. What you have to do is to find the smallest $\lambda$ that gives a non-trivial solution to that differential equation.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you be a little more clear?

Comment: Integrate by parts: $\int_0^1 (f')^2=-\int_0^1 f''f$, hence the min value is $\lambda=\pi^2$ ($f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$, we get the value $\pi^2$. To show that this is the minimum, consider any function $f$ with $\|f\|_2=1$ that has a Fourier expansion. Note that only $\sin(\pi nx)$ terms appear, due to the boundary conditions. Applying Parseval's and evaluating the Rayleigh-Ritz quotient yields a weighted average of the eigenvalues
$$
\pi^2, 4\pi^2,\ldots,
$$
with weights given by the Fourier coefficients of the expansion.

Thus the minimum value is $\pi^2$.